# What is the php regex to capture a set of strings 8, 9, and 10 chars long?

Tags: php, regex

I am dealing with a spambot and in order to prevent its nonsense posts I have determined that it always posts in a specific manner of [8 characters a-zA-Z] [9 characters a-zA-Z] [10 characters a-zA-Z] ...

I want to capture this exact pattern so I can block it.

An example looks like this:

> EifnBTVK zljhGBZty poozgzbdax JZBnNbbpt rbpdig LfpMXMEDqay LfjrLSDQ saxaUBPlc NjflPITJ gccuOZJph

I'm thinking it's something like

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{8}[a-zA-Z]{9}[a-zA-Z]{10}.*/
```

Is that the right line of thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match additionally the empty space between those "words":

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{8}\s+[a-zA-Z]{9}\s+[a-zA-Z]{10}\s+.*/
```

`\s` is a [whitespace character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand)

You can simplify your expression further by using the `i` modifier for case insensitive matching

```
/^[a-z]{8}\s+[a-z]{9}\s+[a-z]{10}\s+.*/i
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this and if it works with a test comment then I'll come back and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding is you could simplify a bit

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{8,10}$/
```

(note this detects each "word", not the entire text)

Comment: This will match only if the whole string is one word with 8 to 10 characters.

Comment: Thank you, however I think stema's answer is more complete.